# How to calculate mean points for elements in a List in R

Tags: r

I have Matrix A and List B as per below:

Matrix A:

```
     [,1][,2]
[1,]   1   1   
[2,]   1   2   
[3,]   2   1   
[4,]   2   2   
[5,]   10  1   
[6,]   10  2   
[7,]   11  1   
[8,]   11  2   
[9,]   5   5   
[10,]  5   6
```

ListB below is the grouping done based on the minimum distance in the order of the rows based on Matrix A. For example, the first four points in List[[1]] is the first four points from Matrix A that is (1,1) (1,2) (2,1) (2,2) and it belongs to Group 1 and so on

List B:

```
    [[1]]
    [1] 1 1 1 1 3 2 3 2 1 1

    [[2]]
    [1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 1 2 3 3

    [[3]]
    [1] 1 1 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 2
```

How can I calculate the mean of the points of group 1, group 2 and froup 3 respectively based on the groupings?

If there is only one vector, this is how I do it:

```
    meanPoints <- apply(MatrixA, 2, tapply, ListB, mean)
```

But how to do a loop to get the the mean points for the List [[1]] [[2]] [[3]] in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do it with `lapply()` to build an anonymous function to handle the iteration through your multiple grouping vectors.

```
# similar data bc I didn't want to type that
MatrixA <- matrix(data = 1:20, ncol = 2)
B <- c(rep(1:3, length.out = 10))
C <- c(rep(3:1, length.out = 10))
listB <- list(B, C)

# just wrapping your single vector solution
lapply(lists, function(x) {apply(MatrixA, 2, tapply, x, mean)})

[[1]]
  [,1] [,2]
1  5.5 15.5
2  5.0 15.0
3  6.0 16.0

[[2]]
  [,1] [,2]
1  6.0 16.0
2  5.0 15.0
3  5.5 15.5
```

Is that what you were looking for?